# LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so line not found in httpd.conf file

Tags: wordpress, apache

I am working on installing ssl on my wordpress file. I want to uncomment these line in httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

Why my httpd.conf file do not have these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the System you use you may need to install openssl (or depending you your Distribution a similar named package).
(also the [arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#TLS.2FSSL) has some useful resources. if you were planning on using self signed certificates letsencrypt is a great source for free 'official' certificates)